# Custom checkbox, change on :hover and :checked. Doesn't work

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, sass

I have problem with my custom checkbox. I would like to change color to green on :hover and yellow on checked.

I tried almost 10 different ways :/ Someone could help me?
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/direct96/pen/eLXMXY)

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">


            <div class="form__checkbox">
              <label for="accept" class="form__checkbox-label">I have read and accept the terms of use.</label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="accept" class="form__checkbox-input">
            </div>

</body>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
  &__checkbox {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    &-label {
      cursor: pointer;
      @include inputFonts();
      margin-left: 46px;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      font-size: 1.6rem;

      &::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 2%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-color: blue;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      &:hover + &::before {
        background-color: red;
        height: 40px;
      }
    }
    &-input {
      position: absolute;
      top: -999999px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `&:hover + &::before` will not work, because you are selecting the next element's psudo-element(`+ &::before`). What (I think) you want to do, is to change the current element's psudo-element.

#### I regards to the hover state, you can change this:

```
  &:hover + &::before { // compiled to: .form__checkbox-label:hover + .form__checkbox-label::before
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
  }
```

to this:

```
  &:hover:before { // compiled to: .form__checkbox-label:hover:before
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
  }
```

This will make the blue checkbox in your example turn red (with 40 px height) on hover.

---

#### Changing color based on checkbox state

In order to do this, you need to do a couble of things:

1. Rearrange the html

   ```
   <div class="form__checkbox">
     <!-- input first! -->
     <input type="checkbox" id="accept" class="form__checkbox-input">
     <label for="accept" class="form__checkbox-label">I have read and accept the terms of use.</label>
   </div>
   ```
2. Add a css selector to your checkbox, targeting the "next sibling label" when `:checked`.

   ```
   &__checkbox {
     // abbreviated...

     &-input {
       // abbreviated...

       &:checked + .form__checkbox-label:before {
         background-color: green;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: 3 hours i trying to fix it.. Thanks!

Comment: @user9325805 Glad to help :) added example for changing the color based on the checkbox' state.

Answer (score 0):

I back to this code, and now I have problem with change checked button. I would like to add grey background and show "checked bird".

I tried various methods and it doesn't work..

Again Link https://codepen.io/direct96/pen/eLXMXY

```
&__checkbox {
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
&-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  @include inputFonts();
  margin-left: 46px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    background-color: $form-text-color;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 4.5%;
    top: 45%;
    background: white;
    width: 2.5px;
    height: 2.5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, 4px 0 0 white, 4px -2px 0 white,
      4px -4px 0 white, 4px -6px 0 white, 4px -8px 0 white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  &:hover::before {
    background-color: $color-input-focus;
  }
}
```